# Table CSS-Style: how to create a conditional CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table, and I need to apply different conditional styles based on a specific attribute value. Here is a snippet of the table that I want to update:

```
<table table-type= "source">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

The attribute that I need to dynamically change is table-type. When a table type is 'source', for instance, I need its background color to be yellow, and if it is 'target', its background color will be red.

Comment: Both answers are correct, I just picked the one with the highest votes, and the time shows that they were answered in the same time. If I could pick more than one answer, I would definitely pick both of you. And sorry that I didn't notice your answer.

Comment: Oh thanks for checking my answer as the solution! I appreciate that.

Comment: Actually, thank you guys a lot for your help. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the CSS attribute selector. Here's a resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```css
table[table-type="source"] {
  background: yellow;
}

table[table-type="target"] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table table-type="source">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table table-type="target">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly simple in CSS, as follow

```
table[table-type="source"] { 
    background-color: yellow;
}

table[table-type="target"] { 
    background-color: red;
}
```